# ¿Cómo puedo acceder a la posicion de una lista dentro de un diccionario en Python?

Tags: python

¡Hola! Mi consulta es la siguiente. Imaginad que tenéis un diccionario como el que os muestro a continuación:

```
dicc={Pedro:['calcetines','pantalones','bañadores'], Luis:['zapatos', 'chaqueta']}
```

La cuestión es si yo por ejemplo quiero acceder a la posición 0 de el valor de Pedro, que sería 'calcetines', como puedo hacerlo. Había pensado que haciendo lo siguiente funcionaría pero me salta error:

```
dicc[Pedro][0]
```

Espero que me podáis ayudar y muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Hola Samuel, si `Pedro` no es una variable que tengas definida previamente y que esté asociada a un objeto hashable, la misma construcción de `dicc` directamente no es sintaxis válida o generará un `TypeError`. Si `Pedro` es en realidad un literal de cadena `"Pedro"`, entonces es un typo sin más, te faltan las comillas en ambos casos, `dicc = {"Pedro: [...], "Luis": [....]}` y `dicc["Pedro"][0]`.

Comment: Agrega siempre la traza completa del error, evita que los usuarios que quieran responder  tengan que estar adivinando, con la posibilidad de dar respuestas que aunque correctas, pueden no resolver tu problema. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

prueba con el siguiente código, a mi me funciona:

```
dicc={'Pedro':['calcetines','pantalones','banadores'], 'Luis':['zapatos', 'chaqueta']}


print (dicc['Pedro'][1])
```

Espero que te solucione el problema.

Un saludo.

Answer (score -1):

El problema radica en las comillas (las que te faltan).

El código sería el siguiente:

```
dicc={'Pedro':['calcetines','pantalones','bañadores'], 'Luis':['zapatos', 'chaqueta']}
dicc[Pedro][0]
```

Te dejo un enlace a un blog que está muy bien explicado,
échale un vistazo

[Devcode.la - Diccionarios en Pytohn](https://devcode.la/tutoriales/diccionarios-en-python/)

PD: La próxima vez adjunta en la descripción el tipo de error.

Un saludo

Comment: La variable Pedro no existe en el código.